# Preloading view from a UITabBar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, preload

I have a class that loads a UITabBarController. Each tab opens a UINavigationController.

I am trying to preload views inside my UINavigationControllers. I tried doing this:

```
UITabBarController * tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.centerController;
NSArray *myViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers;
for (UINavigationController *navViewController in myViewControllers)
{
    [navViewController loadView];
}
```

I tried different things but it never gets loaded. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks Or  Arbel, you actually helped me understand the problem. I had to call `view` on the first UIViewController inside the UINavigationController. Here is the code that works:

```
UITabBarController * tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.centerController;
NSArray *myViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers;
for (UINavigationController *navViewController in myViewControllers)
{
    [[navViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] view];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using auto layout you have to tell the view to layout its subviews accordingly.

Try this

```
UITabBarController * tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.centerController;
NSArray *myViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers;
for (UINavigationController *navViewController in myViewControllers) {
     UIViewController *ctrl = navViewController.topViewController;
     [ctrl.view setNeedsLayout];
     [ctrl.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
UITabBarController * tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.centerController;
NSArray *myViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers;
for (UINavigationController *navViewController in myViewControllers)
{
    [navViewController view];
}
```

Comment: No luck. I think that the problem may come because I have a weird structure:
My UIViewController embed a UITabBarController which embed several UINavigationController which embed a UIViewController.
I tried loading the view of each of them but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UITabBarController {
    func preload() {
        children.forEach { _ = $0.view }
    }
}
```